# is it possible to add a repository in JFrog Artifactory without the GUI?

Tags: artifactory

Is it possible to add a repository in Artifactory without the GUI?

Can I configure Artifactory as infrastructure as code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you use the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository):

```
PUT /api/repositories/new-repo-name
{
  "key": "new-repo-name",
  "rclass" : "local",
  "packageType": "generic"
}
```

Nearly everything you can do in the UI is possible via the REST API, it's pretty extensive. I've run into very few things I can't easily automate this way.

You can also use the [Artifactory Java client](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java) or the [JFrog Go client](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-client-go), which are libraries for Java and Go (respectively) that wrap over the REST API. The latter is quite new from what I can tell, and it may not support everything yet.